# How to restrict generic trait in subtype

Tags: scala, generics, traits, scala-3, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have a trait `Mutable[T]` that describes objects that can be mutated to `T` using a `Mutation` object:

```scala
trait Mutable[T] {
  def mutate(mutation: Mutation): T
}

class Mutation {
  def perform[T <: Mutable[T]](mutable: T): T = mutable.mutate(this)
}
```

I also have two traits describing animals in general, as well as specifically mammals.

I would like to require that an `Animal` can mutate into another `Animal`, but a `Mammal` can only mutate into another `Mammal`. However, the following does not compile:

```scala
trait Animal extends Mutable[Animal]
trait Mammal extends Animal, Mutable[Mammal]

case class Fish() extends Animal {
  override def mutate(mutation: Mutation): Animal = Fish()
}

// error: class Monkey cannot be instantiated since it has conflicting base types Mutable[Animal] and Mutable[Mammal]
case class Monkey() extends Mammal {
  override def mutate(mutation: Mutation): Mammal = Human()
}

// error: class Human cannot be instantiated since it has conflicting base types Mutable[Animal] and Mutable[Mammal]
case class Human() extends Mammal {
  override def mutate(mutation: Mutation): Mammal = Monkey()
}
```

I would like to use these types as follows:

```scala
val mutation = new Mutation()

val fish: Animal = Fish()
val fish2: Animal = mutation.perform(fish)

val monkey: Mammal = Monkey()
val monkey2: Mammal = mutation.perform(monkey)
```

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That is related, but I don't want to return the "current type". Reading that is what lead to this question.

Comment: See also updates

Comment: @Nulano sure, which is why I added a comment rather than an answer. Also, my point was also to show that F-Bound is particularly fragile in this regard nad that maybe a typeclass would be a better approach, or in this case `this.type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want to make `Mutable` covariant?

```
trait Mutable[+T] {
  def mutate(mutation: Mutation): T
}
```

In such case your code seems to compile in Scala 3

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qVMDsu7HRLiBFlSchGxWEA

---

When you were loosening the restriction on `Mutation.mutate` to `[T <: Mutable[? <: T]]` `Mutable[? <: T]` is actually defining covariance at a call site

[In Scala3, if generic type argument(s) is mapped to dependent type, how are covariant & contravariant modifiers mapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75035824/in-scala3-if-generic-type-arguments-is-mapped-to-dependent-type-how-are-cova)

---

Also you can try to make `T` a type member rather than type parameter. In such case the existential type is just `Mutable` while a specific type is `Mutable { type T = ... }` (aka `Mutable.Aux[...]`)

```
trait Mutable:
  type T
  def mutate(mutation: Mutation): T

object Mutable:
  type Aux[_T] = Mutable { type T = _T }

class Mutation:
  def perform[M <: Mutable](mutable: Mutable): mutable.T = mutable.mutate(this)

trait Animal extends Mutable:
  type T <: Animal

trait Mammal extends Animal:
  type T <: Mammal

case class Fish() extends Animal:
  type T = Animal
  override def mutate(mutation: Mutation): Animal = Fish()

case class Monkey() extends Mammal:
  type T = Mammal
  override def mutate(mutation: Mutation): Mammal = Human()

case class Human() extends Mammal:
  type T = Mammal
  override def mutate(mutation: Mutation): Mammal = Monkey()

val mutation = new Mutation()

val monkey: Mammal = Monkey()
val monkey2: Mammal = mutation.perform(monkey)
val monkey3: Mammal = mutation.perform[Mammal](monkey)

val fish: Animal = Fish()
val fish2: Animal = mutation.perform(fish)
val fish3: Animal = mutation.perform[Animal](fish)
```

[Bind wildcard type argument in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75289392/bind-wildcard-type-argument-in-scala) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292260/5249621))

---

Also you can try a type class

```
// type class
trait Mutable[T]:
  type Out
  def mutate(t: T, mutation: Mutation): Out

class Mutation:
  def perform[T](t: T)(using mutable: Mutable[T]): mutable.Out = mutable.mutate(t, this)

trait Animal
trait Mammal extends Animal

case class Fish() extends Animal

object Fish:
  given Mutable[Fish] with
    type Out = Fish
    def mutate(t: Fish, mutation: Mutation): Out = Fish()

case class Monkey() extends Mammal

object Monkey:
  given Mutable[Monkey] with
    type Out = Human
    def mutate(t: Monkey, mutation: Mutation): Out = Human()

case class Human() extends Mammal

object Human:
  given Mutable[Human] with
    type Out = Monkey
    def mutate(t: Human, mutation: Mutation): Out = Monkey()

val mutation = new Mutation()

val monkey: Monkey = Monkey()
val monkey2: Human = mutation.perform(monkey)
val monkey3: Human = mutation.perform[Monkey](monkey)

val fish: Fish = Fish()
val fish2: Fish = mutation.perform(fish)
val fish3: Fish = mutation.perform[Fish](fish)
```

Although type class instances have to be resolved statically while you seem to prefer resolving values dynamically (`val fish: Animal = Fish`, `val monkey: Mammal = Monkey`).

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type

http://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

[Advantages of F-bounded polymorphism over typeclass for return-current-type problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813323/advantages-of-f-bounded-polymorphism-over-typeclass-for-return-current-type-prob)

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by a conflict between `Mutable[Animal]` and `Mutable[Mammal]` in the list of supertypes for `Monkey`.

To resolve the conflict, you can instead use `Mutable[? <: Animal]` which is compatible with `Mutable[Mammal]`:

```scala
trait Animal extends Mutable[? <: Animal]
trait Mammal extends Animal, Mutable[Mammal]
```

Then, to extend the type `Animal`, you have to explicitly add `Mutable[Animal]` as a supertype to be able to override the `mutate` method:

```scala
case class Fish() extends Animal, Mutable[Animal] {
  override def mutate(mutation: Mutation): Animal = Fish()
}
```

It might be helpful to define a helper trait to save a bit of typing:

```scala
trait AnimalBase extends Animal, Mutable[Animal]
case class Fish() extends AnimalBase {
  override def mutate(mutation: Mutation): Animal = Fish()
}
```

However, the type of `Animal` now no longer matches the requirement for `Mutation.perform`, even if you explicitly specify the type parameter:

```scala
val mutation = new Mutation()

val monkey: Mammal = Monkey()
val monkey2: Mammal = mutation.perform(monkey)  // OK
val monkey3: Mammal = mutation.perform[Mammal](monkey)  // OK

val fish: Animal = Fish()
val fish2: Animal = mutation.perform(fish)  // error: Found: (fish : Animal), Required: Nothing
val fish3: Animal = mutation.perform[Animal](fish)  // error: Type argument Animal does not conform to upper bound Mutable[Animal]
```

This can be fixed by loosening the restriction on `Mutation.mutate` to `[T <: Mutable[? <: T]]`:

```scala
class Mutation {
  def perform[T <: Mutable[? <: T]](mutable: T): T = mutable.mutate(this)
}

val mutation = new Mutation()

val fish: Animal = Fish()
val fish2: Animal = mutation.perform(fish)  // OK
val fish3: Animal = mutation.perform[Animal](fish)  // OK
```